# Python: `validators.url` does not accept port number from 1-9, but accept port bigger than 65535?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Fact:** TCP/UDP port number range is started from `1-65535`.

However, I've just noticed that `validators.url` does not accept port number from 1-10?

```
>>> for i in range(1,11): validators.url('http://example.com:%s' %i)
...
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:1', 'public': False})
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:2', 'public': False})
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:3', 'public': False})
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:4', 'public': False})
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:5', 'public': False})
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:6', 'public': False})
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:7', 'public': False})
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:8', 'public': False})
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://example.com:9', 'public': False})
True
>>>
```

It also accept port number bigger than 65535.

```
>>> for i in range(65535,65538): validators.url('http://example.com:%s' %i)
...
True
True
True
>>>
```

Is there any reason for this abnormal behaviour?

Would it be possible to only accept valid port number between `1-65535` with Python3 `validators.url`?

Comment: What is problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the docs](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-validators.url), `validators.url` isn't magic, but relies on a regex. In the specific case of port, [the regex](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294) is

```
    // port number (optional)
"(?::\\d{2,5})?"
```

meaning any number between 2 and 5 digits will work. Thus `01` will work, but single digit integers will not.

You could always add a limitation on top of `validators.url` if invalid port numbers are an issue for you.