# Data Type `NoneType` comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to validate the port number (range `1-65535`) inside URL using `urlparse`.

The tricky part is if the URL doesn't have port number in it, `urlparse(url).port` is identified as `NoneType`

Hence, I tried to make a simple comparison based on the data type, but didn't really work as you can see in this example.

If I use `NoneType` as a data type,

```
elif type(u.port) == NoneType:
```

I'm getting error

```
NameError: name 'NoneType' is not defined
```

I did not use `validators` as it can't validate the port number correctly.

[Python: `validators.url` does not accept port number from 1-9, but accept port bigger than 65535?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910689/python-validators-url-does-not-accept-port-number-from-1-9-but-accept-port-b)

TCP/UDP port number range is started from 1-65535. However, `validators` unable to recognize port `1-9` and still accepting invalid port bigger than `65535`.

**Code**

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def test(url):
    global u
    u = urlparse(url)
    print(' Port      : ', u.port)
    print(' Data Type : u.port %s\n'% type(u.port))

for url in ['example.com', 'example.com:1', 'http://example.com:1']:
    print(url)
    test(url)
    if type(u.port) == int:
        print(' Integer')
    elif type(u.port) == None:
        print(' None')
    # elif type(u.port) == NoneType:        # NameError: name 'NoneType' is not defined
    #   print(' None')
```

**Output**

```
example.com
 Port      :  None
 Data Type : u.port <class 'NoneType'>

example.com:1
 Port      :  None
 Data Type : u.port <class 'NoneType'>

http://example.com:1
 Port      :  1
 Data Type : u.port <class 'int'>

    Integer
```

Comment: There's only one value to `NoneType`: i.e. `None`. So... :-)

Comment: `NoneType` lives in `types` where it is defined as `type(None)`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't compare types to check for `None`, use:

```
elif u.port is None:
    print(' None')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the NoneType by:

```
elif isinstance(u.port, type(None)):
    print(' None')
```